# Rule for an S3 Object Creation event to ignore certain S3 Object Creation events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I have a lambda that is listening for `s3:ObjectCreated:*` events on a bucket.  What it does is pull down the object that is created, manipulate the object a bit, then write the object back to S3... this then triggers the `s3:ObjectCreated:*` event which starts the process again.

This is what my rule looks like:

```yaml
functions:
  processPostmanCollection:
    handler: handler.processPostmanCollection
    description: Handles the manipulation of postman collections to transform to our desired format.
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: example.bucket
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
          rules:
            - prefix: postman-collection-prod/
            - suffix: .json
```

Now when I loop over the records in the event Records, I see that some of the data populated in the record is:

```json
{
  userIdentity: {
    principalId: 'AWS:jehjkfru84378jkdsfh:bitBucketPipeline7654578'
  },
}
```

I only really want to deal with objects created by this BitBucketPipeline userIdentity.  I could add this to the code:

```js
module.exports = async (event, context) => {
  for (const record of event.Records) {
    if (record.userIdentity.principalId.includes('BitBucketPipeline') === false) {}
  }
}
```

But I would prefer it to be some kind of natural rule if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from my understanding you want to transform postman data to your desired format but you got recursive invocation.

You can't filter it by using `principalId`. only prefix or suffix filter are available to s3 events.

So currently I can suggest a few options including your ideal solution.

1. Write back the transformed data to different folder inside the s3 bucket from your lambda. Means if your invocation happens `postman-collection-prod/` then write back to `processed/postman-collection-prod/` or any name you want
2. Use two S3 bucket with the same exact configuration one to upload the other to write back the transformed. If you want to still use folder name `processed/postman-collection-prod` because you got other configuration. Which AWS itself recommended way to do this kind of things.
3. Check on your Lambda if the event is what you want to process or not. But here you are adding a cost because of the lambda will run  and it will cost you.

I know there is additional cost to all of the above solution because of the model AWS use. There is only two option to folder which are `prefix` and `suffix`.

So try using something like `your-file.unprocessed.json` then add that in the
suffix.

```
functions:
  processPostmanCollection:
    handler: handler.processPostmanCollection
    description: Handles the manipulation of postman collections to transform to our desired format.
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: example.bucket
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
          rules:
            - prefix: postman-collection-prod/
            - suffix: '.unprocessed.json'
```

Or create something to identify from the file by either suffix or prefix.

Because Prefixes and suffixes do not support wildcards so the strings provided should be literal.

Comment: I used option 1.  Thank you!

Comment: anytime @Jarede